# How does my HTML form work without a Submit button

Tags: jquery, html

While playing around with a form, I ended up with it looking like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="myscript.py">
    <input type="file" id="file-picker" name="picker" autofocus multiple>
    <button id="upload-btn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Upload</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Despite the fact that the form has no Submit input element, I am able to trigger its action (and run myscript.py") by clicking on my button element.

I haven't added a click handler to the button element.

My question is: How does the form know that clicking on the Upload button should trigger a Submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for the `type` attribute of button elements is "submit". So you have to add `type` attribute to your `upload-btn` as:

```
 <button id="upload-btn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" type="button">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Upload</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<button>` element's behaviour is defined by [the `type` property.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button)

> type = submit/ reset/ button

The default for the `type` property is `submit`, which will submit the form the button is attached to.